# ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!

Tags: 14.04

I have win 10 64bit v 1607 . I tried to install ubuntu 14.04.3 64bit it keeps giving me this error "ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!"
so what should I do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the issue related to Radeon graphic driver. You need to edit the Grub file.

Option-1: If Ubuntu is able to boot:

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="radeon.modeset=0"` or, `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"` and Save the file
3. `sudo update-grub && sudo systemctl reboot`

Option-2: If Ubuntu is not able to boot:

1. To edit Grub during the boot, do the following:
2. Immediately after the BIOS splash screen during boot, press and hold the SHIFT button. This will display you grub containing a list of kernels and recovery options
3. Press `e` to edit the kernel
4. Find the line ending with `quiet splash`. Add your boot option before these key words - i.e. so the line looks like `nomodeset quiet splash`
5. `ctrl+x` to boot

It should work now. Also remember, if you want to permanently use `nomodeset`, then, after boot, follow my Option-1.

Comment: where to write these commands ?

Comment: i'm using win 10 when I try to install Ubuntu the error appears then the ubuntu logo then black screen so i can't open the terminal to write these commands

Comment: Please check my answer again. I have added Option-2 for you.

Comment: thanks for your response , it really helps me & the error is gone but when it open a message appears that there is error in the system , but every thing works fine

Comment: Ignore the message, it's from apparmour, not to give importance till everything works fine. I am happy to help you.

Comment: Happy Ubuntuing :)

Answer (score -1):

I have that problem on hiveos.

I solve the problem reinstalling hiveos.

I reinstall hiveos remote, with this command:
hive-replace --list

Comment: As this is askubuntu and (at least for most stuff) only Ubuntu related problems are allowed to be asked here, I very much doubt he has the "hive-replace" as a command to his disposal. So I voted -1 to your answer.