# Xubuntu 22.10 to 23.04 GUI upgrade login loop. Nvidia drivers purged. No driver for GPU. Nouveau module installed but not in use. How to activate?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nouveau

After solving a login issue caused by an old Yubikey setup (old thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1467818/upgrade-to-xubuntu-23-04-cant-login-popup-loop-tty-login-info-doesnt-work)), I remain in a situation whereby I can enter my password, click login, it throws a blank screen for a second, then shows the login prompt again. I've tried all 3 flavours in the top right corner (xfce, xubuntu, etc), no change.

I purged the nvidia drivers, `lspci` now says the graphics card has no active driver. I have no idea how to select the nouveau driver outside of the GUI - it's already installed, and I backed up and removed `xorg.conf` to prompt it to rebuild that from scratch, still nothing.

Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271613/am-i-using-the-nouveau-driver-or-the-proprietary-nvidia-driver), `grep nouveau /var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

> (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
>
> (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
>
> (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
>
> (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 0
>
> (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
>
> (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
>
> (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
>
> (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
>
> (II) Unloading nouveau
>
> (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 0)

It looks like it's trying to load it twice?

```
lsmod | grep nouveau
```

Suggests it is loaded.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga
```

Should show which driver is in use but the result is:

"grep: vga: No such file or directory".

Completely stumped as to how to get it to use this driver.

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

Gives some interesting bits:

> *-display UNCLAIMED
>
> configuration: latency=0

I.e. no driver again, and unclaimed, whatever that means.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'Kernel modules'
```

> nvidiafb, nouveau

More: [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993853/how-to-select-kernel-driver-in-use-for-gpu) says I can bind a module (nouveau) to a device (nvidia gpu) but there's no nvidia gpu in `/sys/bus/pci/drivers/`.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271613/am-i-using-the-nouveau-driver-or-the-proprietary-nvidia-driver) has various useful approaches but nothing if there's no driver loaded, other than it's not loaded (comments on answer 1). The user said "When booting via BIOS, X ends up using VESA driver, but when booting via UEFI, X cannot start at all" but IDK how they came to this conclusion.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373592/how-to-change-in-use-driver-linux) says you can blacklist modules but nouveau isn't blacklisted (I checked).

Any ideas? `xorg.conf`? I've tried backing up & deleting to no avail. Doesn't seem like anything useful in `GRUB`?

Grub: edit `/etc/grub/default` as root, remove `nomodeset`, save, `sudo update-grub`, reboot. Now using nouveau. But login loop persists...

Spoke to Unit193 in https://xubuntu.org/irc/ seems I had 2 versions of exo in my system. Purged xfce4-screensaver, then exo, then installed exo from lunar repos (sudo apt install exo/lunar), then backed up /usr/local/lib to /evillib and it's now sorted. What an ordeal!

Screensaver bug:

```
xfce4-session: symbol lookup error: xfce4-session: undefined symbol: xfce_screensaver_new
```

How to keep packages current without having to install from github:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/staging
```

Very much helped by termbin.com (cat command | nc termbin.com 9999) and ~./xsession-errors file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with huge help from Unit193 in https://xubuntu.org/irc/, see answer in question.